# How to download a project's big file which uses Git Large File Storage manually?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-lfs

I am trying to clone Mozilla [DeepSpeech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech) but some files (I think the models) are huge so they are transferred to somewhere other than GitHub using [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/) technology. I need this project but my internet connection is not a reliable one so I think it would be a better choice to download the huge files manually maybe using some download manager. Is there any way to do the manual download? If not, what is the alternative solution?

Comment: What is the issue ? Are you not able to clone your project because of large files ?

Comment: As I said the due to my Net connection and the huge files, I cannot finish the clone process.

Comment: What are those file sizes ? Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Maybe about 1.6 GB.

Comment: Have you tried by `gzip` the whole repository & download the `.gzip` file ?

Comment: How would I do so?

Comment: which OS you are using ?

Comment: I on Windows 7 but I have Gow installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download them directly from github, for example:
https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/raw/master/data/lm/lm.binary
[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked! But redirected to [this]( https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/mozilla/DeepSpeech/master/data/lm/lm.binary).

Comment: Yes, you have to wait for a while and it will start downloading the file.

Comment: How do I use curl or wget to download such large file? Is there a way?